# iPad Play HTML5 Audio from dynamic source (servlet/jsp)

Tags: ipad, audio, html

I'm trying to use the HTML5  tag on the iPad.  It works fine if the source is set to a hard-coded file:

```
<audio src="http://...../myFile.wav"></audio>
```

...but if I set the URL to a servlet or ASP.net page it refuses to play it!

```
<audio src="http://...../myDynamicHandler.ashx?audioId=123"></audio>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try this with FireFox v4 or Chrome v11 ?

Answer (score 2):

Are you setting the correct contentType header before sending the wav data?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this problem also bothered me for 6 hours.
Finally I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768812/video-streaming-to-ipad-does-not-work-with-tapestry5) in other topic.