# Jersey REST support resume/media streaming

Tags: rest, streaming, jersey, media, resume

I need to support resume on Jersey REST, I'm trying to do it this way:

```
@Path("/helloworld")
public class RestServer {

@GET

@Path("say")
@Produces("audio/mp3")
public Response getMessage(@HeaderParam("Range") String r ) throws IOException{
    String str="/Users/dima/Music/crazy_town_-_butterfly.mp3";

    System.out.println(r);
    RandomAccessFile f=new RandomAccessFile(str, "r");

    int off=0;
    int to=(int)f.length();
    byte[] data ;
    if(r!=null){
        String from=r.split("=")[1].split("-")[0];
        String t=r.split("=")[1].split("-")[1];
        off=Integer.parseInt(from);
        to=Integer.parseInt(t);

    }
    data= new byte[to-off];
    f.readFully(data, off, to-off);

    ResponseBuilder res=Response.ok(data)
            .header("Accept-Ranges","bytes")
            .header("Content-Range:", "bytes "+off+"-"+to+"/"+data.length)
            .header("Pragma", "no-cache");;

            if(r==null){
                res=res.header("Content-Length", data.length);
            }
            f.close();

            Response ans=res.build();

            return ans;


}
}
```

I want to be able stream mp3 so the browser can seek the music, but in safari it still not working. any ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is my take based on the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768812/video-streaming-to-ipad-does-not-work-with-tapestry5/12829541#12829541). It works correctly on different browsers. I am able to seek the music just fine in Safari and other browsers as well. You can find the sample project on my Github [repository](https://github.com/aruld/jersey-streaming) which has more details. Chrome and Safari nicely leverages the range headers to stream media and you can see it in the request/response trace.

```
    @GET
    @Produces("audio/mp3")
    public Response streamAudio(@HeaderParam("Range") String range) throws Exception {
        return buildStream(audio, range);
    }

    private Response buildStream(final File asset, final String range) throws Exception {
        // range not requested : Firefox, Opera, IE do not send range headers
        if (range == null) {
            StreamingOutput streamer = new StreamingOutput() {
                @Override
                public void write(final OutputStream output) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

                    final FileChannel inputChannel = new FileInputStream(asset).getChannel();
                    final WritableByteChannel outputChannel = Channels.newChannel(output);
                    try {
                        inputChannel.transferTo(0, inputChannel.size(), outputChannel);
                    } finally {
                        // closing the channels
                        inputChannel.close();
                        outputChannel.close();
                    }
                }
            };
            return Response.ok(streamer).header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, asset.length()).build();
        }

        String[] ranges = range.split("=")[1].split("-");
        final int from = Integer.parseInt(ranges[0]);
        /**
         * Chunk media if the range upper bound is unspecified. Chrome sends "bytes=0-"
         */
        int to = chunk_size + from;
        if (to >= asset.length()) {
            to = (int) (asset.length() - 1);
        }
        if (ranges.length == 2) {
            to = Integer.parseInt(ranges[1]);
        }

        final String responseRange = String.format("bytes %d-%d/%d", from, to, asset.length());
        final RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(asset, "r");
        raf.seek(from);

        final int len = to - from + 1;
        final MediaStreamer streamer = new MediaStreamer(len, raf);
        Response.ResponseBuilder res = Response.status(Status.PARTIAL_CONTENT).entity(streamer)
                .header("Accept-Ranges", "bytes")
                .header("Content-Range", responseRange)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, streamer.getLenth())
                .header(HttpHeaders.LAST_MODIFIED, new Date(asset.lastModified()));
        return res.build();
    }
```

Here is the MediaStreamer implementation, which is used to stream the output in your resource method.

```
public class MediaStreamer implements StreamingOutput {

    private int length;
    private RandomAccessFile raf;
    final byte[] buf = new byte[4096];

    public MediaStreamer(int length, RandomAccessFile raf) {
        this.length = length;
        this.raf = raf;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        try {
            while( length != 0) {
                int read = raf.read(buf, 0, buf.length > length ? length : buf.length);
                outputStream.write(buf, 0, read);
                length -= read;
            }
        } finally {
            raf.close();
        }
    }

    public int getLenth() {
        return length;
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, what value should i set to chunk_size?

Comment: I used 1MB chunks in my sample here https://github.com/aruld/jersey-streaming/blob/master/src/main/java/com/aruld/jersey/streaming/MediaResource.java It is used when the client does not sent range upper bound, so we decide to chunk the media in to several bits.

Comment: God I wish I had this for jetty. I can't figure out how to convert it.

Comment: @thouliha Checkout jersey2 [branch](https://github.com/aruld/jersey-streaming/tree/jersey2) that uses Jetty.

Comment: @ArulDhesiaseelan: I have a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31070137/how-to-do-server-side-responses-for-http-ranges? . It would be great, if I could hear your thoughts about it, as I'm also using Jersey.

Answer (score 5):

Since I was facing the same problema, I tried a more general solution[1] with a `ContainerResponseFilter` which will trigger when a `Range` header is present in the request and will work seamlessly with any media-type, entity and resource methods.

This is the `ContainerResponseFilter` which will use encapsulate the output stream in a `RangedOutputStream` (see below):

```
public class RangeResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    private static final String RANGE = "Range";

    private static final String ACCEPT_RANGES = "Accept-Ranges";

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
            throws IOException {
        if (requestContext.getHeaders().containsKey(RANGE)) {
            String rangeHeader = requestContext.getHeaderString(RANGE);
            String contentType = responseContext.getMediaType().toString();
            OutputStream originOutputStream = responseContext.getEntityStream();
            RangedOutputStream rangedOutputStream = new RangedOutputStream(originOutputStream, rangeHeader, contentType, responseContext.getHeaders());
            responseContext.setStatus(Status.PARTIAL_CONTENT.getStatusCode());
            responseContext.getHeaders().putSingle(ACCEPT_RANGES, rangedOutputStream.getAcceptRanges());
            responseContext.setEntityStream(rangedOutputStream);
        }
    }

}
```

And here's the `RangedOutputStream`:

```
public class RangedOutputStream extends OutputStream {

    public class Range extends OutputStream {

        private ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream;

        private Integer from;

        private Integer to;

        public Range(Integer from, Integer to) {
            this.outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            this.from = from;
            this.to = to;
        }

        public boolean contains(Integer i) {
            if (this.to == null) {
                return (this.from <= i);
            }
            return (this.from <= i && i <= this.to);
        }

        public byte[] getBytes() {
            return this.outputStream.toByteArray();
        }

        public Integer getFrom() {
            return this.from;
        }

        public Integer getTo(Integer ifNull) {
            return this.to == null ? ifNull : this.to;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            this.outputStream.write(b);
        }

    }

    private final static char[] MULTIPART_CHARS = "-_1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
            .toCharArray();

    private static final String BOUNDARY_LINE_FORMAT = "--%s";

    private static final String CONTENT_TYPE_LINE_FORMAT = "Content-Type: %s";

    private static final String CONTENT_RANGE_FORMAT = "%s %d-%d/%d";

    private static final String CONTENT_RANGE_LINE_FORMAT = "Content-Range: " + CONTENT_RANGE_FORMAT;

    private static final String EMPTY_LINE = "\r\n";

    private OutputStream outputStream;

    private String boundary;

    private String accept;

    private String contentType;

    private boolean multipart;

    private boolean flushed = false;

    private int pos = 0;

    List<Range> ranges;

    MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers;

    public RangedOutputStream(OutputStream outputStream, String ranges, String contentType, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers) {
        this.outputStream = outputStream;
        this.ranges = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] acceptRanges = ranges.split("=");
        this.accept = acceptRanges[0];
        for (String range : acceptRanges[1].split(",")) {
            String[] bounds = range.split("-");
            this.ranges.add(new Range(Integer.valueOf(bounds[0]), bounds.length == 2 ? Integer.valueOf(bounds[1]) : null ));
        }
        this.headers = headers;
        this.contentType = contentType;
        this.multipart = this.ranges.size() > 1;
        this.boundary = this.generateBoundary();
    }

    private String generateBoundary() {
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        Random rand = new Random();
        int count = rand.nextInt(11) + 30;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            buffer.append(MULTIPART_CHARS[rand.nextInt(MULTIPART_CHARS.length)]);
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }

    public boolean isMultipart() {
        return this.multipart;
    }

    public String getBoundary() {
        return this.boundary;
    }

    public String getAcceptRanges() {
        return this.accept;
    }

    public String getContentRange(int index) {
        Range range = this.ranges.get(index);
        return String.format(CONTENT_RANGE_LINE_FORMAT, this.accept, range.getFrom(), range.getTo(this.pos), this.pos);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        for (Range range : this.ranges) {
            if (range.contains(this.pos)) {
                range.write(b);
            }
        }
        this.pos++;
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() throws IOException {
        if (this.flushed) {
            return;
        }
        if (this.multipart) {
            this.headers.putSingle(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, String.format("multipart/byteranges; boundary=%s", this.boundary));
            for (Range range : this.ranges) {
                this.outputStream.write(String.format(BOUNDARY_LINE_FORMAT + EMPTY_LINE, this.boundary).getBytes());
                this.outputStream.write(String.format(CONTENT_TYPE_LINE_FORMAT + EMPTY_LINE, this.contentType).getBytes());
                this.outputStream.write(
                        String.format(CONTENT_RANGE_LINE_FORMAT + EMPTY_LINE, this.accept, range.getFrom(), range.getTo(this.pos), this.pos)
                                .getBytes());
                this.outputStream.write(EMPTY_LINE.getBytes());
                this.outputStream.write(range.getBytes());
                this.outputStream.write(EMPTY_LINE.getBytes());
            }
            this.outputStream.write(String.format(BOUNDARY_LINE_FORMAT, this.boundary + "--").getBytes());
        } else {
            Range range = this.ranges.get(0);
            this.headers.putSingle("Content-Range", String.format(CONTENT_RANGE_FORMAT, this.accept, range.getFrom(), range.getTo(this.pos), this.pos));
            this.outputStream.write(range.getBytes());
        }
        this.flushed = true;
    }

}
```

[1] https://github.com/heruan/jersey-range-filter