# Streaming output (mp3) from a javax/jetty servlet

Tags: servlets, jetty

I've found a few examples for Jersey:

[Jersey REST support resume/media streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410344/jersey-rest-support-resume-media-streaming)

But I really need an example for how to stream audio from a jetty servlet. I've tried writing the file to the raw response, and while it will play from a browser, it can't seek, or skip to the middle of a song.

I think also I have to use the http Range header somehow, but am not sure how.