# How to do server-side responses for multiple HTTP ranges in one response?

Tags: java, http, http-headers, jersey

I'm trying to find a good example of how HTTP ranges should be handled on the server side. I would like to be able to support multiple ranges. Could somebody please show me an example, or provide some useful links? I've read the RFC, but I'm still a bit confused regarding the multipart stuff.

Comment: What exactly are you confused about and why?

Comment: I need some examples of the headers that need to be returned. I am using Jersey, so some example with it would really help, but a plain Java example would also be highly appreciated as well. :)

Comment: see http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7233#section-4